# Pass list<String[]> through intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I would like to pass `List<String[]>` through intent to activity and then retrieve it. Anyone know a way on how to do it properly ? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intent.putExtra List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543811/intent-putextra-list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would put it in a serializable and then pass the serializable object in the bundle to the next activity.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("list", serializableList);

mainIntent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(mainIntent);
```

`java.util.ArrayList` already implements the `Serializable` interface. so that would be perfect for your purposes.
Then on the other Activity you can use the following code to retrieve the list

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
userInfo = (ArrayList) bundle.getSerializable("list");
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Put your variable in a static property of an object.

ex.

```
 public class Util {

     public static List<String[]>  mystaticlist;

}
```

and access it statically from the second activity:

```
    List<String[]>  mystaticlist = Util.mystaticlist;
```

Answer (score -1):

It's possible, but you need to pass it as a Serializable and you'll need to cast the result when you extract the extra. Since ArrayList implements Serializable and String[] is inherently serializable, the code is straightforward. To pass it:

```
ArrayList<String[]> list = . . .;
Intent i = . . .;

i.putExtra("strings", list);
```

To retrieve it:

```
Intent i = . . .;
ArrayList<String[]> list = (ArrayList<String[]>) getSerializableExtra("strings");
```