# Array displaying weird info [I@63376afa

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, random

I'm trying to randomly select 6 numbers for a lottery application. Then add the numbers to an array. When I try to display the information contained within the array, it returns [I@63376afa. If I display randomInt outside of an array it displays correctly, but that isn't added to an array. If I try to add randomInt to an array after the for loop has been processed I get an error Type mismatch can't convert int to int[] which makes sense.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class PracRandom1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int randomInt=0;
        int[] numArray = new int[randomInt];
        int[] array = new int[5];
        Random randomNum = new Random();{
            for (int i = 0; i <= array.length; ++i){
            randomInt = 1+randomNum.nextInt(6); 
                        System.out.println("Array Random numbers: " + numArray);
            }
}}}
```

Comment: you do not add anything to either array.

Comment: Just discussed a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17508107/2291425

Comment: What do you think it should print and why?

Comment: I want it to print an actual number. If I were to do System.out.println(randomInt) I would get numbers but I need those values to be within an array for the second part of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a human-readable `toString()`, you must use [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28double%5B%5D%29), like this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Java's `toString()` for an array is to print `[`, followed by a character representing the type of the array's elements (in your case `I` for `int`), followed by `@` then the "identity hash code" of the array (think of it like you would a "memory address").

This sad state of affairs is generally considered as a "mistake" with java.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7284322/256196) for a brief list of other "mistakes".

Answer (score 1):

Check out `java.util.Arrays.toString()`.

Arrays do not have a terribly useful `toString()` implementation out of the box.