# How to pass List<Integer> array from one activity to another activity

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have here a array list containing of Integers

```
static List<Integer> var_Pposition = new ArrayList<>();
```

I try this like so, But there's error tells

```
Intent in = new Intent(merchandise.this, PurchasedViewCart.class);
in.putExtra("item_position", var_Pposition); // Cannot resolve method 'putExtra(java.lang.String, java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intent.putExtra List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543811/intent-putextra-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pass to intent as follows:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(merchandise.this, PurchasedViewCart.class);  
intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("myList", (ArrayList<Integer>) var_Pposition );
```

**Retrieve data as follows:**

```
ArrayList<Integer> test = getIntent().getIntegerArrayListExtra("myList");
```

Comment: correct your code buddy.. there should be `getIntegerArrayListExtra` instead of `getStringArrayListExtra`.

Answer (score 1):

Put to intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(merchandise.this, PurchasedViewCart.class);  
intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("myList", (ArrayList<Integer>) var_Pposition );
```

Get from intent

```
ArrayList<Integer> test = getIntent(). putIntegerArrayListExtra("myList");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
   static ArrayList<Integer> var_Pposition = new ArrayList<>()
```

Intent doesn't have putExtra with List parameter. you have to do like,

```
   intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("myList", var_Pposition);
```

or you need to cast it